# Filters and results not working properly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, filter

Filters are not working properly, not all the attributes like 'size' are in the sidebar. Also, when selecting an option to filter on, there are no products found for this selection but in the backend, there are options for this 'size' and also have stock and are visible on just the category page without filters selected.

I've searched allot on the internet to find the right solution but any found solutions didn't fix the issue for me.

I did the following this to find out where the problem might be;
- Changed the theme to just the default Luma theme;
- Cloned the database and used a fresh install from Magento 2.1.* to test if the code was broken in 2.1.12;
- Checked the attributes in the backend to make sure they are configured right;

So my thought right now is that there something wrong in the database, but how to debug this issue further? Did anyone of you encounter this problem and got it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

To display more filters options,
You can do that from admin area : **Stores->Attributes->Product.**

You choose the attribute that you want to display in filter.
You go to storefront propreties and you set **'Use in Layered Navigation' to  Filterable (with results).**

After that you should run indexers. Good luck!